# System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out Error is in expression '{!step2}'

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm getting error in below method line no. 14

Error Message:

> "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out Error is in expression
>   '{!step2}' in component  in page documentxDoc:
>   Class.DocumentController.step2: line 14, column 1"

**Code Is:**

```
 public PageReference step2() {
    String sTempType = null;
    List<Manual_Doc__c> lstMdoc = new List<Manual_Doc__c>();
    Manual_Doc__c oMdoc;
    for(Document tempDoc : lstSelectedDoc){
      oMdoc = new Manual_Doc__c();
      sTempType = tempDoc.sDocType;

      PageReference pagePdf = new PageReference('/apex/DocumentPdf');
      pagePdf.getParameters().put('id', oId);
      Blob pdfPageBlob;
      pdfPageBlob = pagePdf.getContentAsPDF();    
      Attachment attachmentPDF = new Attachment();
      attachmentPDF.Body = pdfPageBlob;
      attachmentPDF.ParentID = oId;
      attachmentPDF.Name = 'TerryTestAttach1.pdf';
      attachmentPDF.Description = 'TestDescription1';
      insert attachmentPDF;

      oMdoc.ObjectID__c = oId;
      oMdoc.Template__c = tempDoc.docId;
      oMdoc.Attachment_Id__c = attachmentPDF.Id;
      lstMdoc.add(oMdoc);
      oMdoc = null;
    }
    if(lstMdoc.size()>0){
      insert lstMdoc;
    }
    pageReference pg = new pageReference('/apex/DocumentMerge_2');
    pg.setRedirect(false);
    return pg;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is probably this [Summer '15 - PageReference getContent() and getContentAsPDF() Methods Behave as Callouts](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213972&language=en_US). The change will be mandatory soon but perhaps someone has opted in early in an org.

The problem would appear when more than one document is selected: the `insert attachmentPDF` of the first document will count as a DML before the second `getContentAsPDF` call. A simple fix, providing the keeping the generated documents in memory does not exceed the [6M heap governor limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), is to add the `attachmentPDF` objects to a list and only do the insert after all the `getContentAsPDF` calls have been made.